# Onmouseout function for table gets called between rows/cells

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image with a onmouseover function which brings up a table with some options over the image (image gets dimmed).  The table has a onmouseout function which should hide the table and show the image again.  Problem I'm having is whenever the mouse goes between rows or cells or even on the link inside a cell, the table flashes, as though the mouse went out of the table.  How can I fix this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s89bL3u/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function dimImg(x) {
            x.style.opacity = "0.3";
            document.getElementById("happinessItems").style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        function normalImg(x) {
            document.getElementById('firstImg').style.opacity = "1.0";
            x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        table{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            width: 495px;
            height: 330px;
            visibility: hidden;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0px;
        }
        table td {
            width: 247.5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

<a href="happiness.php"><img id="firstImg" onmouseover="dimImg(this)" src="img/leftButton.jpg" style="display:inline-block; width:495px; margin-right:5px; -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222); filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)" /></a>
            <table cellspacing="0" id="happinessItems" onmouseout="normalImg(this)">
                <tr><td><a href="#">Coats/Jackets</a></td><td><a href="#">Sweaters/Hoodies</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href="#">Dresses/Suits</a></td><td><a href="#">Tshirts/Tops</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href="#">Shoes</a></td><td><a href="#">Bags</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><a href="#">Accessories</a></td></tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: can I use jQuery to answer?

Comment: @FaizAhmed I was really hoping to stick with plain javascript but if it comes down to it and jQuery will work, I'll change to it...so yeah, give me your idea...

Comment: Can you tell me what is your actual goal, how should be the accomplished result.

Comment: If you check out the fiddle and move the mouse around, you can see the table menu flashing.  I don't want that.  Apparently what it's doing is "bubbling"???  Something with child elements of the table.  I think I found a solution and trying to implement it with my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this how you would want it to work?

http://jsfiddle.net/9s89bL3u/2/

Only css and html in this.

```
.test2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 495;
    height: 330px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.test1:hover table{
    visibility: visible;        
}
.test1:hover .test2{
    opacity: 0.3;        
}

table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 495px;
    height: 330px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
table td {
    width: 247.5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that actually is how I want it to look.  And I'm over here stuck with javascript trying to figure out "bubbling".  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

In case someone needs an answer that uses JavaScript, what worked for me was using `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` instead of `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

`onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` don't bubble so they won't give you the flashing effect when you hover over children.

Answer (score 0):

Remember two important things should be present:

```
<!doctype html> //at the very top of the page

border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" //inside your table tag
```